# Clear text field when keyup function is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to clear a text field after a `keyup` function is triggered.

I used a simple `val('')` to clear but it’s not working. Also if ever. I want my text field to not allow entering period or `.` on the first place, like `.12`.

Here is my `keyup` function:

```
$('#gross-mass').keyup(function(event) {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();

  if (parseFloat(currentVal) == 0.00 && (event.which == 48 || event.which == 96)) {
    //currentVal = currentVal.slice(0, 3);
    currentVal.val(' ');
  }

  $(this).val(currentVal);
});
```

Comment: `currentVal` is a string, not a jQuery object. It doesn’t have a `val` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to use `$(this).val("")`, not `currentVal.val(' ');` (in my example it's just `el.val("")` because I have stored `var el = $(this)`). And you should remove this row before the end of the method: `$(this).val(currentVal);`, because it sets `input`'s value back to `currentVal`. Here is the working example, try to type `0` for example, `input`'s value will be cleared after `keyup` event:

```js
$('#gross-mass').keyup(function(event) {
  var el = $(this)
  var currentVal = el.val();

  if (parseFloat(currentVal) == 0.00 && (event.which == 48 || event.which == 96)) {
    el.val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="gross-mass">
```

Comment: @Dre, did you remove this line: `$(this).val(currentVal);`?

Comment: thanks now its working. but the validation should be on the 2nd decimal place. if I type `0.00` that's the time it will only clear the textfield

Answer (score 1):

`currentVal` isn't a function, it's a string. You can set its value like this:

```
currentVal = ' '
```